# How to make Serial.read() return an integer instead of an ascii value?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I want Serial.read() to return an integer instead of an ASCII value. For example, in the below code if I input 2, I want the output as 2 instead of 50

```cpp
void setup(){
    Serial.begin();
}

void loop(){
    if(Serial.available()){
    int t = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(t);
}
```

Comment: your code does not compile because of a syntax error

Comment: `Serial.read()` returns a byte ... what that byte means to you, is not realted to that fact

Answer (score 1):

If it's a single digit:

```cpp
if (t >= '0' && t <= '9') {
    int numeric_value = t - '0';
} else {
    // Handle the input error.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an alternate method like this

```
void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{
 if(Serial.available()){
    String a = Serial.read();
    int b = a.toInt();
    Serial.println(b);
}
```